# Fire events on more than one element in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mousemove

I have a jquery code

```
$(function() {
    $("input").on("mouseover", function() {
        var a = $('input').attr('name');
        populate(a);
    });
});
```

I have three input elements.

```html
Computer Language: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="language"></datalist>         
        <input type="text" list="language" name= "language" id="search"/>           
    </div>      
    <br>
    Country: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="country"></datalist>          
        <input type="text" list="country" name= "country" id="search" />            
    </div>  
    <br>

    Degree: <br>
    <div>
        <datalist id="degree"></datalist>           
        <input type="text" list="degree" name= "degree" id="search"/>           
    </div>
```

Now, `mouseover` event only fires that have name `language` (or the top input element). Why `mouseover` event is not being fired for 2nd and 3rd input elements?

Comment: don't use `id="search"` for multiple elements

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Note:** The `id`s are not meant to be duplicated. You have used `id="search"` many times.

You need to use the *context-sensitive* `this` keyword:

```
$(function() {
  $("input").on("mouseover", function() {
    var a = $(this).attr('name');
    populate(a);
  });
});
```

***To answer your question:***

The reason being, you are executing the `.attr()` (*which is one of many functions that processes only one element*) on the first matched element.

Comment: I want to ask one more thing that is it fine to use mouseover event? because it calls populate function every time we hover our mouse and it perform whole logic again inside populate function.

Comment: @UmairJameel I would advice you to add a flag to the `populate` function like, adding a class. If the class is present, don't populate it, as it is already populated. This way you can save much cycles.

Comment: I am checking if innerHTML of datalist element is empty then execute whole logic of populate function. Is it fine? I think, there must be more efficient solution (hopefully yours), but mine is working.

Comment: @UmairJameel Does the checking needs to do much? I guess mine's better and fast compared I believe.

Answer (score 1):

You need to refer to the current element which is done using `$(this)` ,
`this` refer to the element that invokes the event. `$(this)` will return the object. While 
`$('input').attr('name')` will refer to the first `input` element

```
var a = $(this).attr('name');
```

[**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/6zuasc82/)

Answer (score 1):

You could use the parameter of your handler:

```
$("input").on("mouseover", function(e) {
       var a = $(e.target).attr('name');
       populate(a);
});
```

e.target is exatcly the element you are looking for.

You can use directly javascript instead to transform the element into a jQuery object:

```
$("input").on("mouseover", function(e) {
       var a = e.target.getAttribute('name');
       populate(a);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In JQuery code you always get **"language"** `input`, because it is first `input` in **dom**, as your code search first `input`.

Change your jQuery code as below:

```
$(function () {
    $("input").on("mouseover", function () {           
        var a = $(this).attr('name');
        populate(a);
    });
});
```